# Get View Order URL for custom email in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to get the **URL of the Order Details page** from where user can see their  order details, because using some 3rd party API I send mail to the customer after the product is shipped.

I tried this code

```
$order = wc_get_order(109);
$public_view_order_url = esc_url( $order->get_view_order_url() );
echo $public_view_order_url; //http://example.com/my-account/view-order/109/
```

but the URL generated by ^^ above code only works for logged in customer. Is it possible to get a **Public URL** so that user don't have to logged in because most of the customer don't have any account. I know for security reason email id and invoice number is needed.

One solution that I think is by creating an *custom page* which will accept `order_id`, `order_key` and `email_id` in GET parameter and query it and display the result; the whole thing I have to create but is there any WooCommerce function/hook for this?

I googled it and also spend time in Woo doc but the result was negative,

Any help or suggation will be very helpfull for me.

Thanks.

Comment: I think that this is not really possible in WooCommerce as it is, because when an order is maid by a non logged user, this is handled by temporary sessions and cookies. So is not possible to display an order afterwards in public mode. Thats why you have a "My account" page with all related orders to a logged customer. **But everything is possible with WooCommerce, developing a custom plugin for that purpose.**

Comment: @LoicTheAztec: I did't knew that so I posted this question, and yes custom I can also create, by _custom page_.

Comment: Use `$order->get_checkout_order_received_url()` function. It works for not registered users also

Answer (score 9):

Not sure if I'm missing something, but it *sounds* like what you want can be achieved with the `Order Received` URL:

`$order->get_checkout_order_received_url()`

This would give you something like `https://example.com/checkout/order-received/12345/?key=wc_order_1ab2cd3ef4g`, which is a direct link to the order receipt shown after a successfully processed order.

This link will show billing & shipping details, order details & payment method by default, and doesn't require that the customer has an account or for them to be logged in.

Comment: the link seems working but gives a warning saying "To view this page, you must either login or verify the email address associated with the order."

how can we bypass this email validation?
all my customers are guest customers and I also don't get email while checkout

Comment: @FaizAli It looks like this functionality was a relatively recent addition by WC - bear in mind I wrote this answer _exactly_ 5 years ago today(!) - but it makes sense for WC to do this from a security standpoint. Also, the title of this question is **Get View Order URL for custom email in WooCommerce** - if your customers aren't receiving emails after checkout, there's definitely something else going on.

Comment: thanks for your reply.
i did some research and found this filter "add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_email_verification_required', '__return_false' );" and it work fine for me now people can view the login without being logged in and without email verification.

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't find a way to do that so I just put a condition in my email. If they have an account, link to the order, if they don't encourage them to make an account for the next order.

```
<p><?php
$email_order_url    =$order->get_view_order_url();

if ( $order->get_user() ) {
    _e( "Your message with <a href='" . $email_order_number . "'>Order 
       Number'</a>.", 'woocommerce' );
    } else {
    _e( "Message to encourage them to create an account on the regular 
       accounts page" , 'woocommerce' );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything you need is in post meta, this works for me when in a loop that can access `get_the_ID()`:

```
<?php $the_order_id  = get_the_ID();
      $the_order_key = get_post_meta($the_order_id, '_order_key', true); ?>

https://yoursiteurl.com/checkout/order-pay/<?php echo the_order_id; ?>/?pay_for_order=true&key=<?php echo $the_order_key; ?>
```

Otherwise, if you can replaced `get_the_ID()` with the Order ID in some other way (however you're getting `109` in your initial question), that would work as well.

Comment: You may want to use `/order-received` instead of `/order-pay`. If the order is already paid for the user won't get an error.

Comment: Burning links is not a good practice, that's why woocommerce has `$order->get_checkout_order_received_url()` so you can get the order-received page dynamically despite the current domain address.

Comment: Care to expand on why that would not be a good practice @svelandiag? And what "burning links" means. Never heard that one before.

Comment: the link seems working but gives a warning saying "To view this page, you must either login or verify the email address associated with the order."

how can we bypass this email validation?